# react native KeyboardAvoidingView padding before time

Tags: react-native

i build mini chat view with react-native.
my screen is build from 3 component

**header

listView

input (the input need to be fixed)**

i'm using KeyboardAvoidingView with padding 
to handel the keyboard 
but i get ugly result 
in the top of my listView
it like i add padding before the keyboard arrived

[you can see the problem in the gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBMYw.gif)

**my code:**

main screen:

```
class Registration extends Component{

    render(){
      return(
        <KeyboardAvoidingView style={Style.continerStyle} behavior="padding">

          <StatusBar
            hidden={true}
          />

          <Header/>
          <RegChat/>
          <RegInput/>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>


      );
  }
}
const Style = {
  continerStyle:{
    flex:1,
    backgroundColor:'#543CDE',
  },
}

export default Registration;
```

my listview:

```
class RegChat extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super()
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(['You should receive a 6-digit code in a moment for verification', 'row 2','You should receive a 6-digit code in a moment for verification', 'row 2','You should receive a 6-digit code in a moment for verification', 'row 2','You should receive a 6-digit code in a moment for verification', 'row 2','You should receive a 6-digit code in a moment for verification', 'row 2','You should receive a 6-digit code in a moment for verification', 'row 2',,'You should receive a 6-digit code in a moment for verification', 'row 2']),
      inputType:'phone',
    };
  }

  render(){
  return(
    <ListView
      renderScrollComponent={props => <InvertibleScrollView {...props} inverted />}
      style={{backgroundColor:'black'}}
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={(rowData) => <RegBubble>{rowData}</RegBubble>}
    />)
  }
}

export  {RegChat};
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this package [react-native-keyboard-spacer](https://github.com/Andr3wHur5t/react-native-keyboard-spacer)

Comment: the same problem

Comment: What about this one [react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view). It can handle keyboard appearance within scrollview component, which, I guess, is what you also have.